# Resolving tcdl tags for DCP and JSP Page - REL tags in combination with JSP tags are not working

Tags: web8.5, deployer, tcdl, jsp

In the upgraded SDL Web 8.5 system.

One of the DCP template output has component link  tag. which is not getting resolved in the web app.

```
<a tridion:href="@@Component.ID@@">
@@Component.Fields.Heading@@
</a>
```

We added this below config tags in the deployer service **tcdl-config.xml** also changed the DCP template output type to REL and republished the DCP components then tested it’s working fine it’s resolving the links for DCP component.

```
<TCDLEngine>
   <Properties> 
    <Property Name=”tcdl.jsp.style” Value=”tags” />
    <Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="jsp" />
    <Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="rel"/>
   </Properties>
</TCDLEngine>
```

but, We noticed that now republished JSP pages on file system RTF field component links are not working.

We can see published JSP pages link tags are getting written as `<tcdl:Link` instead of `<tridion:ComponentLink` tag.

And then we removed the REL tag (`<Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="rel"/>`) in deployer service **tcdl-config** – restarted, and republished the JSP page and tested JSP RTF field component links are working fine and noticed that published JSP page on filesystem has `<tridion:ComponentLink` tags.

The question is: Can tcdl tags be expanded to rel ánd jsp in one environment, depending on the targeted object.
So

- file based jsp - expand tcdl to jsp tags
- Broker based rel dcps - expand tcdl to rel tags

**Note:**

Pages – stored in the filesystem

DCP – stored in DB

Web app Java jsp uses CIL.

Did anyone face this issue?

Comment: Please take look https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000006143

Comment: Thanks for your highlight, It works it's config value is not correct on mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, Found the culprit it's a config issue values are not correct:

**Before:**

```
<Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="jsp" />
<Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="rel"/>
```

**Correct config:**

```
<Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="rel"/>
<Property Name="tcdl.page.target.language" Value="jsp" />
```

Refer to documentation [Enabling publishing of Pages with REL format Dynamic Component Presentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-3ED3EF09-4EE6-48B2-A618-D16634BB9DB8)

Comment: Please accept the link which I have added in my comments as helpful

Comment: I did upvote to your link, which is helpful